# AngularJS window does not render (blank page) but resizing window renders it

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

I have this weird issue with my angular app. It doesn't happen every time but I've been able to consistently reproduce it if I click to it as quickly as I can as soon as my angularjs app loads.

Basically my right pane directive will sometimes render a blank page. This page however appears when I resize the browser window a little bit.

I'm not even sure where to begin looking to resolve this bug. I tried messing around with $timeout and $scope.$apply but it didn't seem to do anything.

Has anyone seen anything like this before and if so, how did you resolve it?

Note the directive I use does use ng-include with a value that is dynamically generated from the custom directive's associated controller.

P.S. Another oddity, if I move my mouse over the allow main dock then it loads the page too. (I assume it's doing an unfocus action on the browser window.) I wanted to see if this was a browser specific issue because of this. Looks like it's only Chrome where this is a problem, as I can't reproduce the problem on firefox.

Comment: can you please add some code here or reproduce it via plnkr/fiddle

Comment: Is it possible that you are using ng-if or ng-show in your parent element. If yes, then it might be happening because of not using ng-cloak. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @swapnesh I'll try to get some code up but it's kind of ingrained in a large app so I don't think I could get a working demo that could reproduce the error.

Comment: @ShubhamAggarwal I'll investigate the cloak issue. thanks!

Comment: I had something similar happen before, in my case I had a ng-grid inside an ng-tab. It would initially render as 1px, but would render correctly when I resized my browser. I think putting the content inside an ng-if caused it to render correctly.

Comment: @MikeR when you put it in the ng-if, what was the condition?

Comment: @ThinkBonobo just remembered that I ended up using a function to resize the browser:
```$scope.fixGridInTab = function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $(window).resize();
    }, 1000);
};``` bit of hack :/

Answer (score -1):

Same problem caused by CSS - display: table, found a solution by changing it to display: inline-block, so check if you have a such.